# C# string to string array

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have a string like this:

```
string example = "123456789@987654321";
```

I want to create a string array, and for each position in the array i want to add a letter. Something like this:

```
string [sizeof(example)] example2;

example2[0] = "1";
example2[1] = "2";
example2[2] = "3";

...

example2[9] = "@";

...

example[18] = "1";
```

and so on, each position having a character of the string example, by order.

Regardless, thanks!

Comment: How about `example.ToCharArray().Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray()` ?

Comment: Could you please explain that piece of code, so i can understand it? Appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get it as an array of **strings**, you can use this code:

```
string example = "123456789@987654321";
string[] example2 = example.ToCharArray().Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Let's break it down since you asked for an explanation in your comment:

```
// get the string into a char array, one character per element
char[] step1 = example.ToCharArray();

// Now let's get this into a collection of string values
IEnumerable<string> step2 = step1.Select(c => c.ToString());

// which we finally turn into an array of strings
string[] exampel2 = step2.ToArray();
```

As noted in comments, `System.String` implements `IEnumerable<Char>` which means the code can be shortened down to:

```
string example = "123456789@987654321";
string[] example2 = example.Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray();
```

---

*However*, I still prefer to write out the `.ToCharArray()` part since the act of enumerating over characters in a linq query is usually not something I do so I would prefer this to not go unnoticed upon revisiting this code. This, however, is just my opinion.

One reason for this opinion is that you really need to know *what* you're intending to use those characters for since a multi-character unicode point might throw a spanner into your loop.

Comment: Doesn't `string` implement `IEnumerable<char>` already? I think the `.ToCharArray()` call is not needed.

Comment: Yes, it does, I just like to explicitly call out that I'm enumerating characters since it is usually an odd thing to do. Usually, when one does this, one relies on strings not containing odd multi-character unicode code points, hence I try to stay away from this type of loop.

Answer (score 4):

This will do the trick:

```
string[] strArray = example.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

Linq Select and ToString will convert each char element to a string and Linq ToArray will put the strings into an array object:

```
using Linq;

string example = "123456789@987654321";

string[] exampleArray = example.Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for String.ToCharArray

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.tochararray(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: As per Lasse V. Karlsen's comment this can easiliy be converted to a string array using and Select LINQ function (or even just using Cast(of ))

Answer (score 1):

`ToCharArray()` is your friend. The resulting array will however be of `Char` type, not `string`. However, you can use LINQ to convert each element to string.

Though one may ask, why do you really want to do that? A string itself is, in almost all conceivable ways, a **char array** (it even implements `IEnumerable<char>`), you can run loops on it, or do other array-level things directly.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
  string strOriginal = "HELLO WORLD";
  string[] arstrLetters = new string[strOriginal.Length];

  for (int i = 0; i < strOriginal.Length; i++)
    arstrLetters[i] = strOriginal.Substring(i, 1);
```